# Search in lookup fields

Tags: lightning, formula-field, object, global-search, lookup-field

I want to **global search** in Salesforce Lightning for a particular field in my custom object which is related to another custom object.

Consider, I have two objects A and B.

```
Object A contains:
f1
f2
..
f4 = Ref of B (lookup field)
..
```

```
Object B contains
g1
g2
...
```

Is it possible if I search for **f4** and can get the value of **g1** also?
I know there is a way to make a copy of g1 in Object A, but this is not the approach I am looking for.

Comment: In visualforce page you cannot unfortunately because search in lookup input is a Lightning feature. However if you look for it there are really good open source repositories that you can use as a custom VF lookup that looks and acts like lightning lookup.

Comment: It would help if you were to [edit] your question to go into more detail about what you mean by "searching in lookup fields" (searching for what, precisely?).

Comment: Aditya, you can use lightning-out to embed lightning components into VF pages which should have all the features of lightning within it.

Comment: @DerekF Please look into it.

Comment: @Aditya Directly mentioning users in the way you just did is considered quite rude.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation present in this link [ https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_lookup_lex.htm&type=5 ] it states "As you type in the lookup field, you see a dynamic list of suggested matches. " can you check once.